# Geometry Nodes. What to enter in the result to get a change in the Z axis?

Tags: mathematics, geometry-nodes

I entered **scale** to control the size of the object, if I want to control its height, what should I enter? I tried dozens of different ways.

[image: attribute math]

Comment: I find this question very unclear.  Perhaps you can rewrite you question to make it more clear

Comment: geometry nodes are still not documented as far as I know and are very much a work in progress. I wouldn't be surprised to still see more changes before it is finished and in release.

Comment: Where do you find these nodes? I am curious...

Comment: @ChristopherBennett geometry nodes, can be enabled from buildbot builds only (geometry-nodes branch)

Comment: Oh, it's from a nightly? Makes sense...

Comment: @susu all of blender hinges on users testing new features, and it is only natural that we get questions about new features. I misspoke about docs, they can be found [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/nodes/index.html#nodes) I would bring it up on meta if you wish to discuss it, blender is changing daily and is releasing faster than ever used to.

Comment: @Timaroberts Then it is time to create a new tag...

Comment: @susu agreed it's only a matter of time before these become commonplace questions once the branch is in master.

Comment: Thank you all @timaroberts I'm really new to Blender. I worked mostly with the "grasshopper" software.  There are a lot of basic things that are missing in geometry nodes.  Where can we talk about it?

Comment: Geometry Nodes project is still in Alpha stage, it may or may not be included in the 2.92 release in a few months, but even then it wouldn't be fully production ready. Expect nodes and workflow to change regularly

Comment: My understanding is that currently what you are trying to achieve is impossible because attribute manipulation is not vectorized : You can tweak the scale depending on an object's position but it will affect all 3 axes at the same time. see : https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1uEH.png In the meantime you can use Animation Nodes which is fairly well documented and not expected to change soon

Answer (score 4):

I guess one solution to do what you are asking is a tree like the following:

[image]
<sup>*Click to enlarge*</sup>

The logic behind this is simple, use a  [*separate xyz node*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/nodes/vector/separate_xyz.html#separate-xyz), and use a [*math>add*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/nodes/utilities/math.html#math-node) before the [*combine xyz node*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/nodes/vector/combine_xyz.html#combine-xyz) to control scale in the [*transform node*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/nodes/geometry/transform.html#transform).
The [*value node*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/nodes/input/value.html#value-node) simply provides a means for uniform scaling in all or multiple axes.

This produces the following result on a [point instance](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/nodes/point/point_instance.html#point-instance) of cubes.

[image]

<sup>Do note that the geometry nodes project is a work in progress, and some features are still being adjusted as development continues.</sup>

Comment: I know that.  I need to pick them up in exact values

Comment: @שלומירשף the answer provides the current way to do what your question (in it's currently written form) is asking. If the answer does not address your concerns, please edit your question to include *all details and information needed* including what you have tried that has not worked so that answers do repeat failed or unwanted results, and wasted time for other users.